# What is the callback function for disabling the multiple selection and checkbox in the multipleSelect function

Tags: jquery, multiple-select

I just wants to disable the multi selection and the checkbox option from the below the below code. Is there any call back function available for this?
My code:

```
$('#denialCodesList-@viewId').multipleSelect({
            isopen: true,
            multipleWidth: 55,
            filter: true
        });
```

Comment: Can you give an example or plugin link which you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding selectAll:false when initialising . From [docs](http://multiple-select.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/)

```
$('#denialCodesList-@viewId').multipleSelect({
        isopen: true,
        multipleWidth: 55,
        filter: true,
        selectAll: false,
});
```

Comment: single:true can solve my issue.. But the another problem was still i can see the check box..user not able to select the option by clicking on the text..they have to hit the check box to select the option..is there any solution for this

Comment: good to hear. Try to wrap the content of the inputs in a `<label><input type='checkbox' >Click this text and input will be selected</label>`
Or add a for and an id attributes to the label and input respectively